# ManyToMany relationship via XML-RPC JAVA

Tags: java, many-to-many, odoo, xml-rpc, openerp-7

I'm using OpenERP 7.0 and I want to set a ManyToMany relationship between my objects in XML-RPC.

[According to the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.write) (Unfortunately for Odoo 8.0) , I have to use special commands that permit to edit those relationships.

For example to set a new ManyToMany relationship I have to use this triplet :

```
 (6, _, ids)
```

Here is my code to create a new message in OpenERP.

```java
models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
                db, uid, password,
                "mail.message", "create",
                asList(new HashMap() {{
                    put("author_id", 10);
                    put("partner_ids", asList(asList(6, 0, asList(34,54,56))));
                    put("subject", "This is a subject");
                    put("body", "This is the body");
                }})
        ));
```

The message is created in OpenERP but the ManyToMany relationship is not set.

So my question is what I'm doing wrong when I want to set this relationship in Java via XML-RPC.